# Tengo Problema en el consumo de una api en heroku con Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, heroku, backend

Hola buenos días comunidad, actualmente tengo un proyecto, esta implementando en nodejs, este proyecto consume una api, que es la siguiente: https://steamcommunity.com/id/emmik/inventory/json/730/2

Yo hice un endpoint en nodejs el cual consume esta api y retorna un json, pero pareciera ser que localmente me anda todo perfecto, en digitalOcean de también, el problema ocurre cuando lo quiero deployar en heroku, me dice Aplication ERROR. y pareciera ser cuando agrego node fetch ya que cuando lo quito y no hago peticiones anda todo perfecto, según investigue pareciera ser que hay que hacer algo extra para consumir una api externa desde heroku.

Este es el método get que estoy usando:

```javascript
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
   let response = await fetch(
      "https://steamcommunity.com/id/emmik/inventory/json/730/2/",
        {
          method: "GET",
          body: JSON.stringify("Hello World!"),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            Host: "https://*.airtableblocks.com",
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
        }
    );
   await res.status(200).send(await response.text());
});
```

Este es el repositorio: https://github.com/gonzalonicolasr/backendTest

repito: localmente me funciona perfecto.

Comment: Que función cumple `await response.text()`? No debería ser `response.json()`?

Comment: devuelve un string simplemente si es lo mismo a ese tmb lo uso al json()

Comment: Tal vez te haga falta: app.enable('trust proxy');

Comment: `node-fetch` deberia estar incluido en los componentes del package. puede que no este reconociendo la llamada fetch() y localmente te funciona debido a que esta instalado globalmente